How to get notes events from Kustomer
I want to set up the outbound webhook for 'notes created' and 'notes updated' events on Kustomer. However, in the event type dropdown, I don't see any option for notes events.
Is there a way to retrieve notes events from Kustomer?
I am looking for a way so that when a notes event happens on Kustomer, I will receive a notification on my current working project

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
